# In which language should the questions be posted? Portuguese or English?

Tags: discussion

In which language should the questions be posted? Portuguese or English?

If a question is posted in a language different from the expected, what should we do? Flag to close or translate and edit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think all contributions (questions, answers and comments) should be allowed in portuguese and/or english.

In the case of a question or an answer, you can always edit it to add a translation. In the case of a comment you can not edit to translate it, but the comments that add value to a question or to an answer could be included in such question or answer, using both languages if appropriate.

Comment: and why not in other languages too?

Comment: Do you mean it would be ok to ask here questions in russian or chinese?

Comment: Yes, I think that if we will accept English and Portuguese makes no sense exclude other languages that are quite used

Comment: This obviously makes sense, but I also think questions not in Portuguese or English may go unanswered.

Comment: Given that English is an international language on the Internet and the defacto language of Stack Exchange, it is only reasonable to support this foreign language. Chinese or Russian are not as internationally widespread as English, and questions in those languages could easily get frowned upon by other users.