# Pode-se pedir traduções para alemão?

Tags: support

Estou estudando alemão, e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer perguntas sobre tradução para esta língua.

Comment: Há [um outro site](http://german.stackexchange.com/) para o alemão.

Comment: Mas naquele site não é possível pedir tradução do alemão para o português. Pelo menos, assim eu entendi.

Comment: Relevante: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/131/well-allow-translations-to-and-from-which-languages

Comment: @spohreis tem de ser para o inglês.

Answer (score 9):

### English (Em Português mais abaixo)

The [Help centre](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has this to say about translations:

> We are not a translation service, nor do we purport to be experts in languages other than Portuguese. Asking about the meaning of a difficult Portuguese sentence is fine. So is asking how to express an idea in idiomatic Portuguese. But please don't ask us to translate a text to or from another language.

My understanding of this is that translation questions should focus on how to express an idea in idiomatic Portuguese, not on the interpretation of the foreign text. This means that before asking a translation question you should make sure you understand the foreign text.

For instance suppose you want a Portuguese equivalent to *Weltschmerz*. In your question you should start by explaining in Portuguese (or English if you're asking in English) what *Weltschmerz* means, and then ask about a good way of saying it in Portuguese. If you are unsure about the meaning of *Weltschmerz*, you should ask a question about it in German SE (they accept questions in English).

Here are a few examples of what I think are good translation questions:

> [Qual seria uma tradução adequada para “redact”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/qual-seria-uma-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-adequada-para-redact)
>
> [Equivalente ao inglês «gasp» — inspirar rápida e audivelmente devido a surpresa ou choque](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/equivalente-ao-ingl%C3%AAs-gasp-inspirar-r%C3%A1pida-e-audivelmente-devido-a-surpresa)
>
> [Equivalent expression in portuguese for “Jack of all trades, master of none”](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/equivalent-expression-in-portuguese-for-jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none)

### Português

O [Help centre](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) diz o seguinte acerca de traduções (tradução minha)

> Nós não somos um serviço de traduções, nem nos apresentamos como peritos em línguas que não o português. Perguntas sobre o significado de frases difíceis em português são bem-vindas, tal como perguntas sobre como exprimir uma ideia em bom português. Mas por favor não nos peças para traduzir um texto para ou de outra língua.

O meu entendimento disto é que perguntas de tradução devem incidir sobre como exprimir uma ideia em bom português, e não na interpretação do texto em língua estrangeira. Isto significa que antes de fazer a pergunta deves certificar-te que compreendeste o texto estrangeiro.

Por exemplo, suponhamos que queres perguntar qual o equivalente em português a *Weltschmerz*. Deves em primeiro lugar explicar em português (ou inglês se fizeres a pergunta em inglês) o significado de *Weltschmerz*, e depois perguntar qual será a melhor de exprimir essa ideia em português. Se tiveres dúvidas acerca do significado de *Weltschmerz*, pergunta primeiro no German SE (eles aceitam perguntas em inglês).

Aqui ficam alguns exemplos de, na minha opinião, boas perguntas de tradução:

> [Qual seria uma tradução adequada para “redact”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/qual-seria-uma-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-adequada-para-redact)
>
> [Equivalente ao inglês «gasp» — inspirar rápida e audivelmente devido a surpresa ou choque](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/equivalente-ao-ingl%C3%AAs-gasp-inspirar-r%C3%A1pida-e-audivelmente-devido-a-surpresa)
>
> [Equivalent expression in portuguese for “Jack of all trades, master of none”](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/equivalent-expression-in-portuguese-for-jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none)

Answer (score 5):

(Bilingual answer: English on top, Portuguese at the end.)

## English

- **tldr**: yes, for de→pt; but for pt→de, ask in [german.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com).

### Questions about German<->Portuguese?

My understanding is that it is on-topic to ask for X→pt, and pt→en.
This I derived from a previous discussion here in meta: [We'll allow translations to and from which languages?](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/well-allow-translations-to-and-from-which-languages)

This includes de→pt, but not pt→de.

If you want to ask questions about pt→de, I would expect them to be on-topic in https://german.stackexchange.com .

### Should I ask about translations?

Go ahead. But observe the general rules about translation-questions that Jacinto highlights in his answer.

And as with any other topic, strive for good quality questions. Do some research, and write clearly.

---

## Português

- **tldr**: sim, para de→pt; mas para pt→de, pergunta em [german.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com).

### Perguntar sobre Alemão<->Português?

Tanto quanto percebo, é *on-topic* perguntar acerca de X→pt, e pt→en.
Cheguei a este entendimento a partir de uma outra discussão aqui no meta: [We'll allow translations to and from which languages?](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/well-allow-translations-to-and-from-which-languages)

Isto inclui de→pt, mas não pt→de.

Perguntas acerca de pt→de devem ser *on-topic* em https://german.stackexchange.com .

### Devo perguntar sobre traduções?

Força! Mas toma atenção às regras gerais acerca de perguntas-sobre-traduções que o Jacinto frisa na sua resposta.

E como em qualquer outro tópico, há que caprichar na qualidade: fazer alguma pesquisa, e escrever com clareza.